# Trying to install virtualenvwrapperwith pip3

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am working to set up a django project on ec2 with an Ubuntu 14.4 LTS instance. I want to write my code using python 3 and django. I've been advised that the best way to do this is to use virtualenvwrapper. I tried:

```
ubuntu:~$ sudo pip3 install virtualenvwrapper   

      Successfully uninstalled six
Successfully installed virtualenvwrapper virtualenv virtualenv-clone stevedore argparse pbr six
Cleaning up...
ubuntu:~$ mkvirtualenv env1
mkvirtualenv: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

edit:

I followed your directions, logged out and logged back in:

```
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.   

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
```

I'm suspecting that this is because I'm installing to python3 which is not the default python interpreter

Answer (score 1):

[From the documentation](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#shell-startup-file)

> **Shell Startup File**
>
> Add three lines to your shell startup file
>   (`.bashrc`, `.profile`, etc.) to set the location where the virtual
>   environments should live, the location of your development project
>   directories, and the location of the script installed with this
>   package:
>
> ```
> export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
> export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
> source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
> ```

In particular, sourcing the shell script above will allow you to run all of the virtualenvwrapper commands.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to point `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` to wherever `python3` is.